# ¿Cómo puedo buscar outliers con outliers_mad agrupando mis datos por tratamiento? y ¿Cómo puedo eliminarlos?

Tags: r, script

Estoy intentando buscar y eliminar outliers de mi base de datos usando outliers_mad. El gran problema con el que me encuentro es que tengo 4 tratamientos distintos y no encuentro como buscar los outliers en cada uno de los tratamientos. Arme tablas por separado para cada tratamiento y realice la búsqueda, pero después me encuentro con el problema de eliminar los valores extremos del dataset original.

Arme tablas separadas para cada tratamiento

```
TTO1 <- datos %>%
drop_na() %>%
filter (TTO %in% c("TTO1"))
```

Busco y gráfico los outliers para cada tratamiento por separado

```
outliers <- outliers_mad(TTO1$X)
outliers
plot_outliers_mad(outliers, x = TTO1$X)
```

Se que no es la mejor manera, pero no se me ocurrió otra forma.
Desde ya agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Entre otros datos, [`outliers_mad()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Routliers/versions/0.0.0.3/topics/outliers_mad) te entrega el valor de cada outlier detectado, pero lo que hay que hacer es aplicar está función a cada grupo:

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(TTO) %>% 
  summarize(X = list(outliers_mad(X)$outliers)) %>% 
  unnest(X) %>% 
  unique()
```

Con esto obtenemos los outliers de cada `TTO`, lo que resta, es "quitar" estos valores de los datos originales, para lo cual podemos emplear un [`anti_join()`:](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/join)

```
datos %>%
  anti_join( 
          datos %>% 
            group_by(TTO) %>% 
            summarize(X = list(outliers_mad(X)$outliers)) %>% 
            unnest(X) %>% 
            unique(),
          by = c("TTO", "X")
  )
```